# Very low quality flag declined

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, low-quality-posts

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66956684/in-weka-for-simple-k-means-clustering-do-you-exclude-class-even-if-it-is-not-a) the other day. The intent is... unclear? Judging from the new user profile, the word "Notes" at the beginning, and the flawless grammar, it looks to me like they just copy/pasted something from their school class, asking it to be explained.

While this "question" technically has a question mark in the subject line, and technically could be "answered" by someone throwing out information about nominal attributes and clustering, this is very low quality.

In my opinion, the question is unlikely to be salvaged through editing, as the content appears has no coherent structure. In fact the body of the question actually just asserts information at us instead of asking anything.

So I flagged the post as "very low quality"... and it was declined. Can I get any tips as to why? Is there a side of this question I missed that the moderator did not? Should I have used a different flag? What should the "very low quality" flag be used for instead? Thank you all!

Comment: If you think a question should be closed, choose one of the close reasons under the "Needs improvement" option. VLQ is for gibberish.

Comment: @JeanneDark This is very helpful, thanks! I suppose my question is less about "what is the VLQ flag" and more about "what would this question be used for if it does not quality as VLQ?". Again, the answers on your linked question seem to fit this question: it pretty much is "garbage", and no editing could turn it from a block of notes into a "question."

Comment: <rant>can we finally do something with how the "Very Low Quality" flag is named? It is a huge waste of time of all good-willing contributors that think that low quality does not mean "outright throw-away garbage"?</rant>

Comment: @OlegValter this is a fair point. I have seen plenty of Meta questions arguing the same thing. And I agree; not everyone's definition of Low Quality appears to be the same. *P.S. nice touch with delimiting your rant with tags :D*

Comment: As you can see from the dupe target, this has been (and still is) a very confusing flag to use. I'd use Shog9's extended description as the name "Obvious Unarguable Garbage" to make it a little less likely to cause confusion, but that would probably be considered as not in the spirit of the "be nice" policy. P.s. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't flag as VLQ what should normally be downvoted or flagged for closure.

This question is just low quality, and it could be unclear - there is a close reason for that, too - but ultimately, if it's otherwise not useful, downvoting is still a reasonable choice.

Comment: Personally, when I came across this question in the reviews, I just flagged it as needing details and clarity - and evidently I was correct as that's exactly what it was closed for.